# Autodesk Forge Data Management DotNet Package

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-data-management

I wonder if there is a forge data management library for dotnet like design automation package.

- https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-design.automation

So I could use data management to store the files used in the design automation in an easy way.

I found some samples, but not compact in a DataManagementClient class.

Answer (score 2):

I created my own package with a simple implementation for the OSS.

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/ricaun.Autodesk.Forge.Oss
- https://github.com/ricaun-io/forge-api-dotnet-oss

Answer (score 0):

We have a .NET SDK that handles Data Management API (among other services).

You can refer to [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autodesk.Forge) and [github](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client).

In this SDK we have classes for each specific Data Management entity, such as:

- [Hub](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/Hub.md)
- [Project](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/Project.md)
- [Folder](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/Folder.md)
- [Item](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/Item.md)
- [Version](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/Version.md)

The most recent version (1.9.7) also covers a simple way to handle binary transfers, as described in [this blog post](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/direct-s3-upload-and-download-sdks).

We are also looking for early adopters of the alpha version of a new SDK for the APS OSS service ([refer here](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/looking-alpha-release-adopters-net-oss-sdk))